# Owin PhysicalFileSystem - Embedded Resources

Tags: c#, owin, embedded-resource, katana

I'm new to Owin and I have an advanced question and I hope it's possible to do that.

I have an web application HTML/JS/CSS and I configured Owin Like This

```
        var url = "http://localhost:8080";
        var root = args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : ".";
        var fileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(root);

        var options = new FileServerOptions();
        options.EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true;
        options.FileSystem = fileSystem;
        options.StaticFileOptions.ContentTypeProvider = new CustomContentTypeProvider();
        options.EnableDefaultFiles = true;


        WebApp.Start(url, builder => builder.UseFileServer(options));
        Console.WriteLine("Listening at " + url);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

And sure enough it works when i add my project in a sub folder and navigate to it Like: http://localhost:8080/test/

What I want to do is to move my files from physical directory to embedded resources and make this embedded resources as my project folder / path for owin.

Can I do that ?? and how can I achieve this !!

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.filesystems(v=vs.113).aspx)? There's an intriguingly named `EmbeddedResourceFileSystem` class in the same place as you can find `PhysicalFileSystem`.

Comment: can you Please give me an example cause when i browse it i can only find TestHTTP.AppResources.resources ... how i can Initiate my index.html from this embedded resource

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [EmbeddedResourceFileSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.filesystems.embeddedresourcefilesystem(v=vs.113).aspx). Then replace in line:

```
options.FileSystem = new EmbeddedResourceFileSystem(typeof(YourClass).Assembly);
```

Comment: I would just like to add to this that you need to dereference along the namespace for it to work "as expected" so the proper setup is actually 

`options.FileSystem = new EmbeddedResourceFileSystem(typeof(YourClass).Assembly, "YourNamespace.YourClass.sourcefolder");`

Provided that your embedded files are in a namespace providing folder called `sourcefolder`

Comment: new EmbeddedResourceFileSystem(typeof(BASECLASS).Assembly, typeof(BASECLASS).Namespace + ".public");